# Broken passwords in Symfony 3.0

Tags: bcrypt, symfony

My Symfony application [loads its user entities from the database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html). Here's the entry in `security.yml`:

```
security:
    encoders:
        MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\UserEntity:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        main:
            entity:
                class: MyBundle:UserEntity
                property: username
```

When I implemented this I followed Symfony’s recommendation to store a unique salt for each user, using it whenever the password is encoded:

```
$encoder = $this->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
$encodedPassword = $encoder->encodePassword($form->getData()->getPassword(), $user->getSalt());
if ($encodedPassword === $user->getPassword()) {
      // Success
}
```

Symfony 3.0 [no longer allows you to pass a salt](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/master/Encoder/BCryptPasswordEncoder.php#L74), so I’ve updated my logic:

```
$encoder = $this->get('security.password_encoder');
$encodedPassword = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $form->getData()->getPassword());
if ($encodedPassword === $user->getPassword()) {
      // Success
}
```

But encoding without the salt obviously doesn't work. Is there any way I can get my users password working on 3.0, short of asking every one of them to reset their credentials?

Comment: The default encode may have changed but the encoder interface still takes a password as well as a salt.  Just configure the encoder to use whatever you did for 2.x and you should be okay.

Comment: Can you let me know how the encoder interface accepts a salt? I can't find this covered in the documentation, and the encode function definitely now ignores the salt: https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/master/Encoder/BCryptPasswordEncoder.php#L74

Comment: Please post the encoder section of your security.yml file.  On my S3 the default encoder the the UserPasswordEncoder which supports a user salt.  Need to figure why you getting the bycrypt encoder.  Did you change anything between S2 and S3?

Comment: Thanks Cerad, I've added the encoder section to my original question. No changes between S2 and S3.

Comment: Resolved! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I wasn't using the `isPasswordValid` function. This recognises the salt that is now stored within the bcrypt encrypted password:

```
$encoder = $this->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
$passwordValid = $encoder->isPasswordValid(
    $user->getPassword(),
    $form->getData()->getPassword(),
    null
);
```